# Select from table using model properties that is not null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I want to select values from table where my model properties that has a value.
This is my Model.

```
public class Library
{

    public IEnumerable<Books> books { get; set; }
    public string BookName { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public int ShelfNumber { get; set; }
}
```

I want to select from table where values are equal to my model property that is filled up.

For Example:

```
public ActionResult(Library lib)
{
    var b = _bookService.GetBooks();
    lib.books = b.Where(x => // select values from table based on the properties that has a value in my model)
}
```

How to do this?

Comment: Please post the Book model, so we can help you to filter based on their value.

Comment: @Brduca my book model has the same properties as Library except for the IEnumerable<>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that properties in `Books` has same names as properties in `Library` you are probably looking for something like this:

```
var b = _bookService.GetBooks();

foreach (PropertyInfo p in typeof(Library).GetProperties())
{
    // skip "books" property
    if (p.Name == "books")
    {
        continue;
    }

    // skip null values from lib
    if (p.GetValue(lib) == null)
    {
        continue;
    }

    // build condition dynamically
    var value = Expression.Constant(p.GetValue(lib));
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof (Books));
    var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Books, bool>>(
        Expression.Equal(
            Expression.Property(param, p.Name), 
            value
        ),
        param
    );

    b = b.Where(predicate);
}
```

`b` must be queryable, if it is not change first line to `var b = _bookService.GetBooks().AsQueryable();`

Answer (score 0):

It will be:

```
public ActionResult(Library lib)
{
    var b = _bookService.GetBooks();
    lib.books = b.Where(x => x.Color == lib.Color && x.ShelfNumber == lib. ShelfNumber && x.BookName == lib.BookName )
}
```

Comment: it will work only if i filled up BookName, ShelfNumber and Color what if i only filled up BookName and Color ? i want to select from table based on my model property that is filled up.